# x-o program in assemly?

Tags: assembly

hello everyone 
I realy need source code of x-o or tic tac toe program in 808186
any body can help me how can I find something like that?

Comment: is this a homework assignment?  please add the homework tag if so.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work: http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/MASM/TicTacToe/ttt_1.html?

Comment: Hmm, Google is your friend ;) Why not just convert it? It shouldn't be *too* hard to do.

Comment: What's to convert from those links?  80186 will run it fine.  The only real difference from 8086 to 80186 as far as programming goes is that the 80186 adds ENTER, LEAVE, and PUSH immed.

Comment: Heh, I just Googled it and posted what I thought would work. The only assembly thing that I have coded was a modified disk drive opener script...

Answer (score 0):

The board has 9 tiles. Each tile has one of 3 states (empty, circle, cross). Give each of these states a number, and use them to calculate the state of the entire board (e.g. "board = tile[0][0] | tile[0][1] * 3 | tile[0][2] * 3 * 3 | tile[1][0] * 3 * 3 * 3 | ..."). This will give you a number from 0 to 19683 representing the current state of the game.

Use the "current state of the game" integer as the index into a lookup table, where each entry in the lookup table represents the new state of the game. This will cost you about 38.45 KiB. Use the highest (16th) bit of each entry to represent "the last player won the game" so you don't need to do much to detect if someone won.

Now write some code (in C or some other high level language) to generate that lookup table. Even simple brute-force techniques should give you a lookup table that represent a perfect opponent without too much trouble (although the point of games is to be entertaining, and a perfect opponent that's impossible to beat isn't fun, so perfection is probably bad in this case).

The only other thing you'd need is user input and display code. Should be fairly easy to do with less than 64 KiB of code/data/stack, so you don't even need to mess with segments.

That hard part will be finding an actual 80186 to test it on (and no, modern 80x86 CPUs aren't as backward compatible as you might think, as there were a few bugs and differences in PUSH/POP if I remember right)...

Comment: None of the processor bugs should come into play with something this simple.